# box-shadow on top of children

Tags: html, css

How do I get an inset CSS3 `box-shadow` to render on top of its children elements?

Problem:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="chatroom">
    <div class="chatmessage"><b>User 1:</b>Test</div>
    <div class="chatmessage"><b>User 2:</b>Test</div>
    <div class="chatmessage"><b>User 1:</b>Test</div>
    <div class="chatmessage"><b>User 2:</b>Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#chatroom{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 135px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    overflow: auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.55);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.55);
}
.chatmessage{
    padding: 4px 2px;
}
.chatmessage b{
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.chatmessage:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #EEE;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

cant be done directly from css.. (*it is not shadow if it goes above overlapping elements*)

you would need to rework your html a bit by adding a div (or use a pseudo element as suggested by [miguelcobain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223089/128165) answer) to overlay the shadow and your CSS to make the new div have the shadow..

```css
#chatroom {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  height: 135px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
}

.chatmessage {
  padding: 4px 2px;
}

.chatmessage b {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.chatmessage:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatroom">
  <div class="chatmessage"><b>User 1:</b>Test</div>
  <div class="chatmessage"><b>User 2:</b>Test</div>
  <div class="chatmessage"><b>User 1:</b>Test</div>
  <div class="chatmessage"><b>User 2:</b>Test</div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a follow up question. As you can see #chatroom has an overflow set to auto so it is scrollable once filled with enough content. When you scroll the div, the shadow element scrolls as well. Is there any easy way to match the sizes? I tried setting the shadow's height using scrollHeight, but that seems flaky. Any ideas?

Comment: So we're basically hacking stuff again. This is sad. :(

Comment: It works but it is unusable in my case. I have buttons and it makes it impossible to click anything. But really nice little tricks if anyone wants to add that to images.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix, for such a case, you can use the css [`pointer-events:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events/) property (*[for modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)*) on the `.shadow` element..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli `pointer-events:none` doesn't work at all though. (Tested on `::after` pseudoelement.)

Comment: @Senthe works fine for me at https://jsfiddle.net/bfhskn92/ Post your code if you want more help

Answer (score 41):

To avoid the use of an additional element, you can use css pseudo-elements. Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/karlhorky/79Vpp/).

```
#chatroom {
    position: relative;
}

#chatroom:before {
    content: "";

    /* Expand element */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.55);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.55);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.55);

    /* Disable click events */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Basically this css creates that additional element for you. Notice the `pointer-events:none` to allow click events to pass through this element.

Keep in mind that `pointer-events:none` doesn't work well on some mobile devices regarding touch scrolling (clicking/taping works well). I ended up not using inset shadows at all because of this.

Comment: Doesn't work too well if the #chatroom element is a scrolling element.  Any ideas?

Comment: @KimballRobinson The way I fixed it was by creating an extra div, one outside with a shadow and one inside that scrolls.

Answer (score 4):

Change the background-color of any children to also be RGBA (this only gets set in browsers that understand it which, conveniently, is any browser that can handle the shadow):

```
.chatmessage:nth-child(2n) {
    background : #EEE;
    background : RGBA(0, 0, 0, .066);
}
```

Note that the two colors (`#EEE`, `RGBA( 0, 0, 0, .066)`) are identical as long as the background behind them is white.

Demo since people seem to be down voting this for no reason: http://jsfiddle.net/6NrkR/

Comment: mind explaining why this was down-voted when it works perfectly well and is a better solution than the accepted answer?  any browser that supports `box-shadow` also supports RGBA.

Comment: This just seems like a poor solution. However it looks good in practice. So +1 from me.