# CSS box-shadow above children, but keep interaction

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have read several topics like:

- [display box shadow above the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657685/display-box-shadow-above-the-text)
- [CSS3 box shadow on top of children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402473/css3-box-shadow-on-top-of-children)

and many others, but I could not find an answer for what I search for. When an element is placed above other elements, the interaction with these is broken (no events coming through). This means, the underlying text can not be selected or an elements events are not triggered. Here's a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4W24K/).

As you can see, there are two problems.

1. As already mentioned, text can not be selected nor the hover-event is propagated to the `div.hover` element.
2. The size of the `div.shadow` element is not absolutely correct. That is why part of the `div.hover` element is out of the shadow-box (and there, the hover-event reaches the hover-element).

For the first problem, I'd appreciate a CSS only solution, but I'd be satisfied with some JavaScript as well.

---

*Appendix*: Problem 2. on Mozilla Firefox 15.0.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) property. Set it on `div.shadow` per this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4W24K/1/).
2. I cannot see what the issue is (using Chrome 23).

**Update**

For #2 remove the fixed height on `div.wrapper` and add `overflow: auto` (this will allow the margin on `div.hovered` to have some effect on `div.wrapper`). See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4W24K/2/).

Comment: 2) Please see my edit (screenshot). :)

Comment: 1) Wow, awesome!! Never heard about that property, but it works just perfect. (:

Comment: Updated my answer given your screenshot.